# Using Hibernate in Client-Server Model

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm having problems considering using Hibernate in a Client-Server Model.

I want to use a Server which manages the Database Connection and executes Hibernate commands, so the server shall has exclusive Database Access.
The Client should retrieve the mapped Objects from client.

While it is not hard to pass objects to the client when using `FetchType.EAGER` in mapping how to use `FetchType.LAZY`?

My research came out for using Hibernate Custom Proxys. Is this the right way to go?

For Example I have the following two tables in my database

Person Table

```
| ID | FirstName | LastName    | ContactInformation |
|:---|:----------|------------:|:------------------:|
| 1  | Xavier    | Tester      | 1                  |
```

ContactInformation Table

```
| ID | EMail                | phone           |
|:---|---------------------:|:---------------:|
| 1  | xavier.tester@tst.de | 123456          |
```

Assuming this tables are mapped to the `Person` class, with ContactInformation `FetchType.LAZY`.
The Client requests the Person with `ID=1` from the server. Now the server should send the Object to the client, and the client should have the option to call `getContactInformation()` and the server should interpret it using Hibernate`s LAZY.

How is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I came up with two possible solutions:

1. Detach Entity at Server and initialize all Lazy types. When sending from client to server merge it.
2. Building a REST-API

As of now I'm going to use solution number 2